# What to use between performsegue and shouldperformsegue to execute segue if only the condition is TRUE

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am having a hard time in solving my own issue regarding `segue`. The scenario should be when the user tapped the `backbutton` it will prompt an alert which will ask the user *Are you sure to leave this page?* `Leave` or `Stay` are the option. If the user tapped `Leave` response, it will go back to the `DashBoard` and if the user tapped `Stay` it will just retain to its original `ViewController`. The problem is the `segue` automatically executes without checking the condition inside the `backbutton`. I am new in swift and all issues I encountered and encountering are very new to me. How will I construct my codes correctly to meet the requirements of the `backbutton`. How will the button executes first the condition before it performs segue? Hope you can help me. Below are my codes for your reference. Been here for almost 1 week. Thank you.

**performSegue**

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDashBoard" {
        if let dashBoardVC = segue.destination as? DashBoardViewController {
            dashBoardVC.validPincode = validPincode
            dashBoardVC.participants = participants
            dashBoardVC.event = event
        }
    }
}
```

**backbutton**

```
 @IBAction func backbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let alert = SCLAlertView(appearance: confirmationAppearance)
   _ = alert.addButton("Leave", action: {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDashBoard", sender: sender)
    })
    _ = alert.addButton("Stay", action: { })
    _ = alert.showError("Confirmation", subTitle: "Are you sure you want to leave this page?")

    }
```

**trying to use shouldPerformSegue but I don't know how to start**

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if identifier ==  "showDashBoard" {

        var segueShouldOccur: Bool!

        if segueShouldOccur == false {
            print("nope, user wants to stay")
            return false
        }
        else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDashBoard", sender: sender)
            print("Yep, the user wants to leave")
        }
    }


    return true
}
```

**screencapture for storyboard segue**
[image: back button]

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of someone who's like me, newbie in using swift. I solved my own issue. I omitted the segue connected between the `back button`and `DashBoard`. I transfer the segue from `ParticipantsViewController` going to `DashBoardViewController`.:) [image: segue]

```
@IBAction func backbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = SCLAlertView(appearance: confirmationAppearance)
    _ = alert.addButton("Leave", action: {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDashBoard", sender: sender)
        })
    })

    _ = alert.addButton("Stay", action: { })
    _ = alert.showError("Confirmation", subTitle: "Are you sure you want to leave this page?")
}
```